# Lightswitch - Publish Greyed out in Configuration Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013, lightswitch-2012

I am attempting to publish my Migrated VS2012 -> VS2013 lightswitch application. I had to upgrade my project after 2012 decided that auto-generating my new tables code was just too hard for it.

2013 worked the charm, everything went back up and I continued development and I could continue to run the client (desktop) with no issues!

But now I've gone to publish for a client to do UAT on and I cannot publish. I hit publish and I get "This Item does not support previewing" down the bottom and nothing happens. My Configuration manager looks like this:
[image: Congiguration Manager]

I cannot click on deploy.

and the migration log looks like:

[image: migration report]

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I've also found my Output is showing:
Build has been canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightswitch 2012 was dead...  Had to upgrade to 2013,this caused a heap of breaks, but eventually I got it publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by installing an update for Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013. In VS2013 I had an update located here:

Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates